# WordPress wp_query $value = ALL

Tags: php, wordpress

I using a WP_Query that works very well. Now I want to add the ability for user to NOT filter by "cat" or "city".

So can I just specify $category by a special char like "*" or "%" to day "ALL values"? Didn't find it for now... Should I use another way? Thanks

```
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'cat'     => $category,
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'usp-custom-rdvp_city',
      'value'   => $city,
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'key' => 'usp-custom-rdvp_date_event_start',
        'value'   => array( $fromDate, $toDate),
        'type'    => 'DATE',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'usp-custom-rdvp_date_event_end',
        'value'   => array( $fromDate, $toDate),
        'type'    => 'DATE',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Filter by Category

> So can I just specify $category by a special char like "*" or "%" to day "ALL values"?

No. Instead you want to not include the `cat` parameter when you want all of the categories.  Okay, so think about that.  How would you achieve an either/or query arguments within one piece of code?

You dynamically add the `cat` parameter *if there is a category specified*.

```
if ( $category ) {
    $args['cat'] = $category;
}
```

### How about the city?

Use the same approach as we did above with the category.  If there's a city, then add the meta query for that city.

```
if ( $city ) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'     => 'usp-custom-rdvp_city',
        'value'   => $city,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
}
```

### Complete Arguments

Let's put it all together then.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'usp-custom-rdvp_date_event_start',
                'value'   => array( $fromDate, $toDate ),
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'usp-custom-rdvp_date_event_end',
                'value'   => array( $fromDate, $toDate ),
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            ),
        ),
    ),      
);

if ( $category ) {
    $args['cat'] = $category;
}

if ( $city ) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'     => 'usp-custom-rdvp_city',
        'value'   => $city,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
}
```

BTW, you don't need to specify `'post_type' => 'post'`, as it's set to a `post` by default.

Comment: thanks I'm using your solution. I was thinking a value "ALL" was existing, sadly not, but anyway your solution is working, thx

Comment: @Iteration If any of the answers solved your question to your satisfaction, remember to mark that answer by checking it.  It helps the Community. Learn more http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I can't cause I don't have 15 reputation, sorry